# Array doesn't persist outside viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

I'm facing a strange problem with NSUsrDefaults. Whenever I'm fetching the data from NSUserDefaults, it's getting populated temporarily. I'm fetching it into viewDidLoad where it's fetched.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
companies = [NSMutableArray array];
oldCompanies = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"companyData"];
if( companies )
{
    for( NSData *data in oldCompanies )
    {
        companyObj = (Company*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
        [companies addObject:companyObj];
    }
}
}
```

But outside viewDidLoad, whenever I try to access the data, the array "oldCompanies" as well as "companies" are shown "nil".

EDIT:
I'm encoding my Company object in a class which subclasses NSCoding like shown below but not allocating or retaining the properties anywhere. Can this be the catch?

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
//Encode properties, other class variables, etc
[encoder encodeObject:self.companyId forKey:@"id"];
[encoder encodeObject:self.companyTitle forKey:@"title"];
[encoder encodeObject:self.companyImage forKey:@"image"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
self = [super init];
if( self != nil )
{
    //decode properties, other class vars
    self.companyId = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"id"];
    self.companyTitle = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"title"];
    self.companyImage = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"image"];
}
return self;
 }
```

Can anybody please help?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+array` creates an autoreleased array - if you want to take ownership of it per the [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) then you need to retain it:

```
[companies retain];
```

Or create it so that it isn't autoreleased:

```
companies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Or, better, let [declared properties](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html) do that for you:

```
// interface, property declaration:
@property(retain, readwrite) NSMutableArray *companies;

// implementation:
@synthesize companies;

// ... using it:
self.companies = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: It's not working even after retain. Is it something related to NSUserDefaults memory management?

Comment: @neha: What does *"not working"* mean? Is it still `nil`? Empty? Does the app crash? Is your mouse emitting purple smoke?

Comment: @neha: If its still `nil` it either was never set or overwritten afterwards. Did you check that `-viewDidLoad` is invoked first, e.g. via break-points or traces? Are you sure nothing else overwrites it afterward?

Comment: @Georg: I'm going through all the breakpoints, viewDidLoad is invoked first and there's not a single release in the class. P.S. I'm declaring and allocating the variables in this class itself.

Comment: My NSUserDefaults are all set with the values but persisting the fetched values is what I'm failing at. Is there any "NSUserDefaults Memory Managment Guide" which I can refer to?

Comment: @neha: The user defaults do not behave differently in that regard, there is some other problem.

Comment: @Georg: Thanx for your patience. Can you please check my edited question, I wanted to know wheather encoding the object properties the way I'm doing is right or not.

Comment: @neha: If those properties are declared as `retain` or `copy` that should be fine. Have you tried to `NSLog()` *a)* `oldCompanies` directly after getting it from the user defaults and b) `companyObj` directly after unarchiving it? Is either of them `nil` or empty?

Answer (score 1):

You are not retaining the array, when you dont do an alloc, or a retain when instatiating an object you get an autoreleased object, in your example companies is autoreleased and is why you cant access it anymore at a later point you should either alloc it 
[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] or retain it [NSMutableArray array] retain]...either way refer to memory managment guide to learn about objective-c memory managment [memory managment ref](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)

Comment: Even after _companies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; [_companies retain]; array is nil outside viewDidLoad. Is it something related to NSUserDefaults memory management?

Comment: u dont do both, you do one or the other, either way you must be doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access the data before the view is loaded?

Objective-C doesn't reset your pointers for you. If the array isn't "persisted", then the pointer will point to garbage.